# Laravel 5.6: assertSessionHasErrors resulting in "Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed" Error

Tags: php, laravel, testing, laravel-5.6, laravel-testing

I'm trying to set up a test that checks that incomplete forms cannot be submitted to a database and I keep running into issues, currently every time I run phpunit this is what I get:

[image]

My test is set up as so:

```
public function test_incomplete_form_cannot_be_submitted()
{
  $user = factory(User::class)->states('confirmed', 'normaluser')->create([
      'id' => '1',
  ]);
  $form = factory(Form::class)->states('incomplete')->create(['status' => 'submitted', 'user_id' => '1', 'id' => '5',]);

  $this->actingAs($user)->post(route('forms.store'), $form->toArray());

  $this->assertSessionHasErrors(['company_name', 'form_info', 'uploads', 'state']);
}
```

And the factory to set up the incomplete form is set up as followed:

```
 $factory->state(App\Form::class, 'incomplete', function (Faker $faker) {
  return [
    'company_name' => null,
    'form_info' => [
      'contact_fname' => null,
      'contact_lname' => null,
      'address1' => null,
      'dist_city' => null,
      'zip_code' => null,
      'multiple_locations' => null,
      'dist_phone' => null,
      'dist_email' => null,
      'company_website' => null,
      'additional_company_info' => null,
      'company_ownership_structure' => null,
      'business_manager' => [
        '0' => [
          'title' => null,
          'name' => null,
          'phone' => null,
          'email' => null,
        ],
      ],
      'business_planner' => [
        '0' => [
          'title' => null,
          'name' => null,
          'phone' => null,
          'email' => null,
        ],
      ],
      'sales_rep_compensation' => null,
      'midlevel_manager_compensation' => null,
      'sales_state' => null,
      'county' => [
        '0' => null,
      ],
      'split_county' => null,
      'split_county_details' => null,
      'other_brands_represented' => [
        '0' => null,
      ],
      'other_brands_in_territory' => null,
      'company_sales_approach' => null,
      'vision_for_us' => null,
      'who_purchases_the_beer' => null,
      'anticipated_spending_details' => null,
      'what_other_products' => null,
      'chain_retail_coverage' => null,
      'total_size' => null,
      'last_full_year_sales_for_craft' => null,
      'other_breweries_pursue' => null,
      'describe_packaged_beer_space' => null,
      'describe_cooler_space' => null,
      'firkin_handling_procedures' => null,
      'secure_storage' => null,
      'describe_recoup_area' => null,
      'describe_trucks' => null,
      'pos_storage_areas' => null,
      'quality_policies' => null,
      'product_rotation_systems' => null,
      'draft_department_capabilities' => null,
      'channel_focus' => null,
      'channel_focus_details' => null,
      'in_house_signs' => null,
      'sign_printers' => null,
      'sign_shop_employees' => null,
      'other_ownership' => null,
      'other_ownership_details' => null,
    ],
    'state' => 'Alabama',
    'uploads' => [
      'top_25_accounts' => null,
      'first_year_sales_estimate' => null,
      'packaging_space_images' => [
        '0' => null,
      ],
      'storage_images' => [
        '0' => null,
      ],
      'marketing_signage' => [
        '0' => null,
      ],
    ],
  ];
});
```

I have already tried changing the test from factory...->create to factory...->make, modifying the assertSessionHasErrors to only check for ['uploads.top_25_accounts'] and making the $form just an empty array, but nothing has seemed to work.

Comment: Did you receive the same error with `factory(Form::class)->states('incomplete')->make(...)` ? It looks like the factory is trying to create a new entry in the database but `company_name` cannot be NULL and throws an exception, therefore your assertion is never reached.

Comment: Weird, now the test simply gives me an error message of "Error: Call to undefined method Tests\Feature\FormTest::assertSessionHasErrors()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1:**

Your assertion is never reached because `create()` on your factory tries to create a new entry in the database, but `company_name` cannot be `NULL` and it throws an exception.

**Solution:**

Change `create()` to `make()`.

```
$form = factory(Form::class)->states('incomplete')->make([
    'status' => 'submitted', 
    'user_id' => '1', 
    'id' => '5',
]);
```

**Problem 2:**

You have to call `assertSessionHasErrors()` on the response object. `$this->assertSessionHasErrors)` does not exist.

**Solution:**

```
public function test_incomplete_form_cannot_be_submitted()
{
  $user = factory(User::class)->states('confirmed', 'normaluser')->create([
      'id' => '1',
  ]);
  $form = factory(Form::class)->states('incomplete')->make([
      'status' => 'submitted', 
      'user_id' => '1', 
      'id' => '5',
  ]);

  $response = $this->actingAs($user)->post(route('forms.store'), $form->toArray());

  $response->assertSessionHasErrors(['company_name', 'form_info', 'uploads', 'state']);
}
```

Comment: I had to specify the subsection of uploads (uploads.top_25_accounts) but besides that this did the trick, thank you!